# exit status 1 error compiling for board arduino/Genuino Uno when tone code is used

Tags: arduino-uno, sound

I am just trying to use an ultrasonic sensor with a buzzer but the buzzer doesn't respond to my code. I mean it doesn't make any sound. I tested it to check if by sending 5 volts to it, it will make a sound.. and it did... but using this code below... for some reason, it doesn't make any sound....

```
#include <NewPing.h>
#define TRIGGER_PIN 11
#define  ECHO_PIN 12
#define buzzer 13

NewPing sonar1 (TRIGGER_PIN, ECHO_PIN);

long inches1;
int sound = 250;

void setup (){

  Serial.begin (9600);

  pinMode (TRIGGER_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (ECHO_PIN, INPUT);
  pinMode (buzzer, OUTPUT);

}

void loop () {

  inches1 = sonar1.ping_in();  
   if (inches1 <= 5 ){
 //   sound = 250;
    tone(buzzer, 1000); // Send 1KHz sound signal...
    delay(1000);        // ...for 1 sec
    noTone(buzzer);     // Stop sound...
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print (inches1);
    Serial.print ('\n');
   }
  delay (200);
}
```

Comment: don't use tone() if it makes sound with 5 V. only set pin HIGH

Comment: hhhmmmm.....
i see... i will try.. thanks for your answer... :)

Comment: what exit code are you talking about?

Comment: What's the whole message the Arduino IDE gives you. Exit 1 usually means you've got a missing library or a syntax error in your code.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look at the complete error message you will see that there is a collision between the libraries **NewPing** and **Tone**.

```
Arduino: 1.8.9 (Windows Store 1.8.21.0) (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `timer0_pin_port':

(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_7'

libraries\NewPing\NewPing.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.
```

Comment: yes, but the point is that they don't have to use tone()

Comment: I agree! But the question is "error" and perhaps someone take in the information that libraries can have conflicts, I have seen it to many times.